# Flask login_manager displays 'Please log in to access this page' when user enter homepage address

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

When the user enters the home address in flask, flask login_manager redirects it to login page and displays 'Please log in to access this page'. How do I remove this message?

I know that we can customize this message using

```
login_manager.LOGIN_MESSAGE = "jwowijfeowief"
```

But how do I completely remove this message?

Comment: are you using the @login_required decorator for your endpoints? Also provide a screenshot displaying exactly what happens during runtime or enough code to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
login_manager.login_message = ''
```

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.